# Need help to solve Apple crash report

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

Apple is blocking my app because "it's crashing on launch" but actually is in internal test since several weeks and 3 (me included) are testing the same build and it's working properly... So I'm not able to understand what's going on...

Can someone be so gentle to help me in translating this crashlog sent to me by Apple?

Thank you!

PS: I was obliged to cut a small part at the end as the "body is limited to 30000 characters"

```
{"app_name":"AR Meter","timestamp":"2017-09-01 18:06:11.90 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"6a8afc68-3287-3de8-89a4-bc3372c7d7cc","adam_id":1276976367,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.pietromessineo.AR-Meter","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.0 (15A5327g)","incident_id":"0FB9930D-7C3A-41A1-8277-069D2DA0DC16","name":"AR Meter"}
Incident Identifier: 0FB9930D-7C3A-41A1-8277-069D2DA0DC16
CrashReporter Key:   5c74cf2ca5599163e6c94299acbf87aecd536b48
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             AR Meter [427]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/AR Meter
Identifier:          com.pietromessineo.AR-Meter
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.pietromessineo.AR-Meter [487]


Date/Time:           2017-09-01 18:06:11.7613 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-09-01 18:06:11.7433 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A5327g)
Baseband Version:    6.16.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARConfiguration | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/AR Meter | Expected in: dyld shared cache | in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/AR Meter
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x000000010324e9dc 0x103220000 + 190940
1   dyld                            0x000000010324e1b4 0x103220000 + 188852
2   dyld                            0x000000010324e1e0 0x103220000 + 188896
3   dyld                            0x0000000103224498 0x103220000 + 17560
4   dyld                            0x00000001032276dc 0x103220000 + 30428
5   dyld                            0x000000010322121c 0x103220000 + 4636

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000004   x2: 0x000000016e8ea500   x3: 0x00000000000000a2
    x4: 0x000000016e8ea100   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000016e8ea880
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x612e726574654d20  x11: 0x654d2052412f7070
   x12: 0x3842413039344433  x13: 0x74654d2052412f30  x14: 0x412f7070612e7265  x15: 0x00726574654d2052
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016e8ea100  x21: 0x00000000000000a2  x22: 0x000000016e8ea500  x23: 0x0000000000000004
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x0000000101514000  x26: 0x0000000103262000  x27: 0x0000000103262398
   x28: 0x0000000103261f88   fp: 0x000000016e8ea0d0   lr: 0x000000010324e1b4
    sp: 0x000000016e8ea090   pc: 0x000000010324e9dc cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x101514000 - 0x10151ffff AR Meter arm64  <6a8afc6832873de889a4bc3372c7d7cc> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/AR Meter
0x101540000 - 0x101547fff libswiftARKit.dylib arm64  <d63a6eb5b2a73678af7db2878e0d2cae> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib
0x101554000 - 0x101567fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <810bb89ffdf937a592d891140c95f06f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x101588000 - 0x1018fffff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <5e37389576b3378cb388c9bbf8ef5986> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x1019ec000 - 0x1019f7fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <2bdd6c92c7c93698b7a7f5a5bcc659bd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x101a04000 - 0x101a0bfff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib arm64  <93efd28422073eef81b5e8698193adbc> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
0x101a28000 - 0x101a37fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <846bf7753340378cae497615ab28066a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x101a60000 - 0x101a67fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <ad33de098b7d3637bc29df7b9f19d932> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x101a78000 - 0x101a7ffff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <872583a8c09f39a69af64010a4f991eb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x101aa4000 - 0x101aabfff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <0857d96e44f8339c95049cb14c98f062> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x101ac4000 - 0x101ae3fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <aeb7d6d7f60a3a3aae99325bdc2ba035> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x101b00000 - 0x101c5ffff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <5696693b7ddd3ccd8d1ffc27ce5fdf5f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x101ccc000 - 0x101cd3fff libswiftGLKit.dylib arm64  <e51b3665638e3e0ebccb3d86e98fb5f8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftGLKit.dylib
0x101cdc000 - 0x101ce3fff libswiftMetal.dylib arm64  <d2c78923e3b536058b5df23547040ce3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
0x101cf0000 - 0x101cfbfff libswiftModelIO.dylib arm64  <13fc8cc860ac336aac2d1e0eac3272b4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftModelIO.dylib
0x101d10000 - 0x101d17fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <78f3aedb7d5a30d392bd3bf1ea345321> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x101d40000 - 0x101d47fff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib arm64  <d33c9ed2a4c732b8af3ba0b735eccd4e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
0x101d58000 - 0x101d5ffff libswiftSceneKit.dylib arm64  <a722227a490d3d08a6d4c3a65d4a18d5> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
0x101d6c000 - 0x101d73fff libswiftSpriteKit.dylib arm64  <5a630724d4893468ad35d2493b25ab38> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
0x101d80000 - 0x101d8bfff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <77ecba8b8f823633b553f86c32ab49d9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x101d98000 - 0x101dc7fff libswiftsimd.dylib arm64  <ce88d107e28a3c9789cb56d2a8b16011> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
0x101df0000 - 0x101df7fff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <ed86775d666c322ead229bb3f71ec036> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/521D06CD-A2AC-4348-8846-0CB3D490AB80/AR Meter.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x103220000 - 0x10325ffff dyld arm64  <53f59e77b50a3a129d7cb641655cf407> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183365000 - 0x183366fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <16861e4373bb3c81bab15fd7f4f8186a> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x183367000 - 0x1833c0fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <b5750788b63b3612b8bbfb2da1e3dbca> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1833c1000 - 0x1833e1fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <9dc64e3f9d1a31ffbd425695d02c3fea> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1833e4000 - 0x1837dbfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <3f9f36b8549b3c6787c4c080e8778483> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1837dc000 - 0x1837e0fff libcache.dylib arm64  <1c2482db399b3120b79763db3f7eaf8e> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1837e1000 - 0x1837ecfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <991a549a0ac03b42bcf4c7b4c1373914> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1837ed000 - 0x1837f0fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <95d29998c5093551addce17d60637edd> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1837f1000 - 0x1837f8fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <5439e6faafdf3e3da93e7651f4f352a7> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1837f9000 - 0x18385bfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <056fa5087aaa3613b3a9840c1975b550> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18385c000 - 0x1838c0fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <099b89e15eab3cf4bff5db799c09b92c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1838c1000 - 0x1838dbfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <e61c2a71e9023055b42db0ababb9c452> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1838dc000 - 0x1838dcfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <421edb25336d35ce845d051c8f54c2c4> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1838dd000 - 0x1838e2fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <58ff32fa1fad36efb3650480ef799d4b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1838e3000 - 0x1838e4fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <5cd5604a582f3c6cbb5c1185ca7e5536> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1838e5000 - 0x1838fcfff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <df1dc5a5c938383bb49bd98c9e66b15a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1838fd000 - 0x1838fdfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <a496fa878a0336f7aa23022f6a147636> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1838fe000 - 0x18397cfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <27236c80cb8d32f8862467d3e9a18c79> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18397d000 - 0x183981fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <0930020ff8513965a4293c0a1553a9d3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x183982000 - 0x183987fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <c7e8d00ab89a3bde8767c9a195b247cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x183988000 - 0x183989fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <f38c1b51c2773418bbb3353e3c6e5949> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18398a000 - 0x18398bfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <d181da90de973e92ab04ec6071a3020d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x18398c000 - 0x183992fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <89b6f9ab72ab3d83b8a9e6effeda88dc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x183993000 - 0x1839d0fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <10d6fc224dfc3f809d99bafb66cb4a73> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1839d1000 - 0x1839f8fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <de7617857223386b85802be83d9c2132> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1839f9000 - 0x183a26fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <240513ae028a31008dfb31108cbdc208> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x183a27000 - 0x183a45fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <89375584850431fdad4c5d9b7805cb24> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x183a46000 - 0x183ae5fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a523a939c5d13c63b3aa4a08ab6cf035> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x183ae6000 - 0x183af1fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <58aa3be3e592344f9105129b53d92747> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x183af2000 - 0x183afcfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <07ed4d3917aa36e699dd590c90b521fc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x183afd000 - 0x183b06fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <919ad334f6c2382face36e848d71fd89> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x183b07000 - 0x183b16fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <9ccb20a905923c5fbdc0eb06922b34ae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x183b17000 - 0x183b1afff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <c5684ccc8c463d99916e74804b4a2739> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x183b1b000 - 0x183b22fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <d4df12fa41be3c1b8bb215e79f66204d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x183b23000 - 0x183b36fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <29e8d3170872339c94db37b70a0d23ec> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x183b37000 - 0x183b3cfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <c7864c6295e138ba89cc319ff88891d8> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x183b3d000 - 0x183b3dfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <a2f28508977932149724163952169c76> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x183b3e000 - 0x183b67fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <3086c6b2ecda34878d131da998fe7c5a> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x183b68000 - 0x183d88fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <511abe1b57743e76a627ab12d9b7fafe> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x183d89000 - 0x183d9afff libz.1.dylib arm64  <3d5ad144ebf234f08f8fa6317ed61e38> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x183d9b000 - 0x18412bfff CoreFoundation arm64  <1c6b110bf7c13bda98abc86b568ac451> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18412c000 - 0x18413cfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <71af2a23cc5b376f9545b56f43ab78c1> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x18413d000 - 0x18413dfff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <0462669dfa083154bc08a2d0ca04d6bc> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x18413e000 - 0x1841c2fff IOKit arm64  <9cac182a1ec338fa831eeb2b82415660> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1841c3000 - 0x1842acfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <375572194230337fa5612241c5cc0e70> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x1842ad000 - 0x1842bafff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <15b80930d08f330fba800e8b567d8dcf> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1842bb000 - 0x1842d3fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <739cf02ed7013b1d96266ccfef8c4094> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1842d4000 - 0x184430fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <3bc906246c5b3c4da4c6800f51cab8aa> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x184431000 - 0x184455fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <95e228a92943318c8d0c86e12323ca10> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x184456000 - 0x1847b2fff CFNetwork arm64  <24a8a24275c03cc18cdb84e3d00c90ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1847b3000 - 0x184aa4fff Foundation arm64  <4762593179b731f58ade3b824201ac53> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x184aa5000 - 0x184b7bfff Security arm64  <87100a6159723611b19853152f0538a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x184b7c000 - 0x184be8fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <4a99dfc593fe313bb64f8df3aa81b276> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x184be9000 - 0x184c1ffff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <3a1641e6b85c3f88a85e6130aba10c38> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x184c20000 - 0x184c20fff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64  <b799047134a1359d8e2ca4856079a79d> /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x184c21000 - 0x184c37fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <94a38f26f920313b8927f8fb4cefcaf6> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x184c38000 - 0x184c61fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <fba52cfa1567328f8dc7e63c6ef28cd4> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x184c62000 - 0x184d0afff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <9a03e9ddc8313fcd99ad3925423ae0f4> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x184d0b000 - 0x184d22fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <09e0323cf36e3563abb6fa6b5dbef304> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x184d23000 - 0x184d24fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <79d7d6b8384d32d186fe96414abc10b7> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x184d25000 - 0x184d26fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <bf7d0a0f22b83733b6a495859601ba29> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x184d27000 - 0x184df8fff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <c4100e0eae13382f8891952e06984d1e> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x184df9000 - 0x184e2bfff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <58f14baef9283b7984022df9fe368f81> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x184e2c000 - 0x184e61fff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <c2f277e642e03472885dac7156fd6e08> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x184e62000 - 0x184e6afff IOSurface arm64  <d019493a0b0632518cabcdd56436a005> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x184e6b000 - 0x184f10fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <8eef4271b09c30559e7964cd2a5ea258> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184f11000 - 0x185240fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <f6bb57872aac3aa5897d506b120be14d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x185241000 - 0x1854adfff vImage arm64  <1d02d86de0fa39388148068e1517099c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1854ae000 - 0x1854bffff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <bc10c7c259e93f2c9e5508b812a969dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1854c0000 - 0x1854e4fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <9744827de4e930b3a9effb653df2d860> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1854e5000 - 0x18550efff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <cbd0fc51fad13555b977a7e4fd6344de> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x18550f000 - 0x185524fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <a8348fb8d2c73226b491716566b0210f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x185525000 - 0x185529fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <7469159bd64738dab467d905432295fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x18552a000 - 0x185580fff libSparse.dylib arm64  <017e8aaae84b3ffc9a7ff428cb2ddc47> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x185581000 - 0x1855f9fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f2325f789f4b34cca0862961c3d81aa1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1855fa000 - 0x1855fafff vecLib arm64  <1cfa494bc66730d79c6440df00e68a49> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1855fb000 - 0x1855fbfff Accelerate arm64  <4e55f70c680a3eab9d72f569fea9f1f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1855fc000 - 0x185611fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <0ccda387a1cb39ac852fd372f1f3d6e3> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x185612000 - 0x185b54fff CoreGraphics arm64  <2cd7a02fd29230a6af43a2259dcffe7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x185b55000 - 0x185b5dfff IOAccelerator arm64  <304b014332f237f8ad2540ce89aab4d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x185b5e000 - 0x185b61fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <d68e6afea982301ba931d432639e1dbe> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x185b62000 - 0x185bf5fff Metal arm64  <769a790f03fa3c88b41341f51f28262a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x185bf6000 - 0x185c09fff GraphicsServices arm64  <b0b991c0edc233539ef9504dfd95a9b7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x185c0a000 - 0x185d5efff MobileCoreServices arm64  <3857865bce0033a9b343ab34023b4212> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x185d5f000 - 0x185d61fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <09250f64cad635528c892caa6f717815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x185d62000 - 0x185da3fff AppleJPEG arm64  <20e77516fad03857887e83288d0fffa2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x185da4000 - 0x18634dfff ImageIO arm64  <d64e147326623827a7a3739019ded93a> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18634e000 - 0x1863b1fff BaseBoard arm64  <d4c727458e723675a70ada7c529fe8e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1863b2000 - 0x1863c8fff AssertionServices arm64  <f44ff3228bb23b2b877e9ac64b69689b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1863c9000 - 0x1863d1fff CorePhoneNumbers arm64  <f3767b2174a93c338f54b28f13a5f915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePhoneNumbers.framework/CorePhoneNumbers
0x1863d2000 - 0x186416fff AppSupport arm64  <8ca7179835d33b8e971c37a9b20ff9e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x186417000 - 0x18642efff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <b198f8da1ee935489941285eeb25fa20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18642f000 - 0x186434fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <6fe2049fe29d36bbbd686f6d6c400807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x186435000 - 0x1864b9fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <f5ccf5905dcd39e98f7401c02ac35974> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1864ba000 - 0x1864d9fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <bc42441b397630e0a3f8ddbae5291683> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1864da000 - 0x186505fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <e998d04e0f63378e8f79df4968ca4a6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x186506000 - 0x186539fff BackBoardServices arm64  <05a1237daa7f3c97a8ed9f4418720b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18653a000 - 0x186595fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <41fe76b622ad37d0ac80f6f1b667cc6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x186596000 - 0x1865d2fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <f420603fe7c83a3f936a14367285f6a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1865d3000 - 0x1865e1fff PowerLog arm64  <150895042ca635f79eca835263eece15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1865e2000 - 0x1865fdfff CommonUtilities arm64  <49ee5deb22253737b0acd346dfced605> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1865fe000 - 0x186608fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <30c98dbbb1443cf5997f812546d25c87> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x186609000 - 0x1868fffff CoreData arm64  <e74d90ff127b3a128d6ae505b2d15018> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x186900000 - 0x186906fff TCC arm64  <8c4178d5ee2e3a50bcd49236f1766824> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x186907000 - 0x18690efff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <4fb896b54ba43807b72fb4fdccb7f063> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x18690f000 - 0x18699cfff CoreTelephony arm64  <7ee719ccb7ca3860af6fbb1264e62dc8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x18699d000 - 0x1869f3fff Accounts arm64  <f12335cccc8839fdaeaafe87dbef38d5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1869f4000 - 0x186a1dfff AppleSauce arm64  <95f8556fa991380b9a3514cd3919593f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/AppleSauce
0x186a1e000 - 0x186a26fff DataMigration arm64  <cd9136dbbc823609af5b32340704b9f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x186a27000 - 0x186a2dfff Netrb arm64  <fc2cda509fda300585aeb6bcea6bf335> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x186a2e000 - 0x186a60fff PersistentConnection arm64  <13cb5d0f9f1e3942bd53a247a4c0f96a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x186a61000 - 0x186a71fff libmis.dylib arm64  <2712f46f4e653a54b2c522453a9f2ec2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x186a72000 - 0x186b70fff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <4d89cc34ed663377b5e5ebe0937f3081> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x186b71000 - 0x186b76fff libReverseProxyDevice.dylib arm64  <16c290d0b5ae3fd0b951d3fe6e55984b> /usr/lib/libReverseProxyDevice.dylib
0x186b77000 - 0x186b88fff libamsupport.dylib arm64  <5ffba5bc6f0d38deab8cfa1be3811663> /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib
0x186b89000 - 0x186b8efff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <de409a181a3a3c1d9af5e5721d0a1c1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x186b8f000 - 0x186b90fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <98de632b8ab13d84bbe583dd218ba8d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x186b91000 - 0x186b94fff libutil.dylib arm64  <be1fe75d868931caaec05dfb006efa84> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
0x186b95000 - 0x186bd6fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <66431dd4255e349ca10e9b35aa8b5e30> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x186bd7000 - 0x186c43fff APFS arm64  <b9f307421c3630368740a041648ea962> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/APFS
0x186c44000 - 0x186c75fff MediaKit arm64  <14651128d07d3a2a9d4e77ec4475889b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/MediaKit
0x186c76000 - 0x186c8cfff libSERestoreInfo.dylib arm64  <0fd735c386963794a15d758b278e7eb1> /usr/lib/updaters/libSERestoreInfo.dylib
0x186c8d000 - 0x186cc9fff DiskImages arm64  <d4658ce988d73aef9e2d2c16a88b9a6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/DiskImages
0x186cca000 - 0x186cd4fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <e74e5261304b393cb00a95cef3fd4d26> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x186cd5000 - 0x186d1cfff libauthinstall.dylib arm64  <0f768f95355639b99257274ba809136f> /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib
0x186d1d000 - 0x186d25fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <0418abd44ca73a889449c5334c97bedb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x186d26000 - 0x186d31fff OpenGLES arm64  <1d1426a2aefc3c2c9ee41f3105be545a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x186d32000 - 0x186db9fff ColorSync arm64  <6326bf0b3c96321a854a21126d2fcbbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x186dba000 - 0x186de3fff CoreVideo arm64  <82f778c8273e3ceb92c21eeb0aa3df5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x186de4000 - 0x186de5fff libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib arm64  <aa1fabebcfc9315889189c94c6b19c7e> /usr/lib/libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib
0x186de6000 - 0x186f47fff CoreAudio arm64  <febfb24b32a33c60bf8b0ef71f0fed3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x186f48000 - 0x186f76fff CoreAnalytics arm64  <aa1935cf59463deda123026cd24979d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
0x186f77000 - 0x186f7afff UserFS arm64  <3ba178e8ab3c3db4aec1d0a6cf69c515> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x186f7b000 - 0x187231fff CoreMedia arm64  <cd9a16a7ff283455974a258ab4f19060> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x187232000 - 0x187244fff libprotobuf-lite.dylib arm64  <0347768194ca37f781d19289abeb6c5b> /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
0x187245000 - 0x1872a9fff libprotobuf.dylib arm64  <cf04455b3bf83d34ae188d21d074eceb> /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x1872aa000 - 0x18756efff libAWDSupportFramework.dylib arm64  <a8318392f5043fcb8e853e0aa3f9f46e> /usr/lib/libAWDSupportFramework.dylib
0x18756f000 - 0x1875b5fff WirelessDiagnostics arm64  <483b4dae317c3dfeb82ab283cb9cd1ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x1875b6000 - 0x1876a4fff VideoToolbox arm64  <81100d4387b333d898fab10063467d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x1876a5000 - 0x1877b0fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <5dcd159c189130f1902dbc0e8f026c07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x1877b1000 - 0x1877b2fff FontServices arm64  <c1bead613ac336169fe3ec23a15b4453> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x1877b3000 - 0x187902fff CoreText arm64  <7457317a2e4c3117b3302199693409f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x187903000 - 0x187912fff IntlPreferences arm64  <5caad04d33bf38338064bed18e258c0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
0x187913000 - 0x18791bfff RTCReporting arm64  <a7c6117e818a35ec987339c04f566be4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RTCReporting.framework/RTCReporting
0x18791c000 - 0x187984fff CoreBrightness arm64  <ef208eefbe3e343fb8454419ce337ffc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness
0x187985000 - 0x18798ffff libAudioStatistics.dylib arm64  <e8967148c9943b1f9d14188ed4b1e065> /usr/lib/libAudioStatistics.dylib
0x187990000 - 0x187eddfff AudioToolbox arm64  <e75281272f4b3bb8b9d026c62d198a81> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x187ede000 - 0x1880e0fff QuartzCore arm64  <78f1ec350f633578b842c7a83e67859f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1880e1000 - 0x1880ecfff MediaAccessibility arm64
```

Comment: Are you distributing the app for internal test via test flight?

Comment: Yes and on all the devices it's working good...

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods ? Please share more informations

Comment: yes, I'm using cocoapods just for import the Apple advertisement resources.

Comment: Is it possible that you have used a new ARKit API which is not available on iOS 11.0(first beta) but on later versions and you are testing your code on latest iOS 11 beta?

Comment: That can be true... I have developed an ARKit app... But I'm not sure about the availability of the API in some of the beta releases as I'm on the latest one...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `ARConfiguration` is available only on iOS 11.0 and higher:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration?language=objc

Since iOS 11 hasn't been released yet, referencing ARConfiguration in the binary will cause your app to fail to launch on the latest non-beta version of iOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ARConfiguration is working good in iOS 11 beta 9... Can it be possible that in Apple they haven't update their devices to the latest iOS Beta version?

Comment: It's not too far-fetched to me to assume that they'd be testing against the latest released version, which would still be 10.x.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka: On the crash logs, the OS version mentioned is iPhone OS 11.0 (15A5327g)

Comment: Ah crap, so it is. Hrm. One thing I do notice is that while libSwiftARKit.dylib is listed in your binary images, ARKit.framework doesn't seem to show up in the list. Are you sure you're linking against it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, the fact is that ARConfiguration is working on the beta version... It's pretty strange...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for the crash is that ARKit requires an iOS device with A9 or later processor.

> ARKit requires an iOS device with an A9 or later processor. To make
>   your app available only on devices supporting ARKit, use the arkit key
>   in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section of your app's Info.plist.
>   If augmented reality is a secondary feature of your app, use the
>   isSupported property to determine whether the current device supports
>   the session configuration you want to use.

Apple introduced A9 processor in 2015 with iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S plus.
But iOS 11 will be supported in **iPhone 5S** and **iPhone SE**.

You can verify by testing your app on these devices or simulators(running on iOS 11).

Comment: I have put on the info.plist the requirement for ARKit supported devices so I think it's impossible that they are trying to test it on unsupported devices. At least they can do it on the simulator as it's appearing over there "Hardware Model: xxx" ... I don't really know...